# C++ calling a inherited method of a templated superclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I don't understand why the following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void printTuple(T tuple) {
        std::cout << "Hello1!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:    
    void printTuple(std::string name, T tuple) {
        std::cout << "Hello2!" << std::endl;

        printTuple(tuple);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> d1;
    d1.printTuple("Test", 13);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

main.cpp:19:25: error: no matching function for call to Derived::printTuple(int&)'

But shouldn't Derived inherit a method with such a signature from Base?

Thanks

Comment: `Base::printTuple(tuple);`, or else add `using Base::printTuple` somewhere in the definition of `Derived`. As written, `Derived::printTuple` hides `Base::printTuple`; read about name lookup rules in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Hiding also happens if the signatures are different?

Comment: Name lookup happens first. Only if name lookup finds more than one function name, overload resolution is performed over those functions. Roughly speaking, name lookup starts from the current scope and searches "outwards" (in enclosing scopes) and "upwards" (in base classes); it stops as soon as the name is found (even if it later turns out that the entity thus named is not suitable in a given context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to the top of the `public` part of `class Derived`:

```
using Base<T>::printTuple;
```

This will expose the base class overload of the function, i.e. prevent it from being "shadowed."

Answer (score 3):

You should change the line `printTuple(tuple)` to  `Base<T>::printTuple(tuple)` because a function of the base class has been **hidden**.

Comment: It hasn't been overloaded, no. It's been hidden.

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. @Barry I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: Even though John's "using" answer is more convenient for the general case (you always call the superclass method), I prefer this one because it still allows you to call the subclass method if you need it.